Android image segmentation app runs faster when not plugged into android studio
So I created a simple app that runs a torchscript model and performs inference on about 100 images. When I have the phone plugged into my machine and run it through android studio I get 300ms per image. When unplugged and the app is ran I get 180ms per image. Does this make sense or does anyone know why this would happen?
Tested multiple times to confirm.
The images are saved as assets in the application.

my guess: debugging happens. that has a nonzero cost. or maybe the phone thinks it can charge, and that affects resource usage.
